# Imageview not Loading in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard

New to iOS. Imageview in storyboard isn't showing up when run in simulator. I don't see any constraint issues as well. Height of imageview is 40.
Blue background color in image attached is "ImageView"

- Imageview is not hidden
- Imageview is on lightgray view and even added in code as subview
- Image below of storyboard is like how I'm expecting it to be

[image: Please refer image]

Kindly suggest how to achieve

Comment: How are you setting the image on the imageView?

Comment: I added imageView as child of lightGray View in storyboard and gave constraints as top , left , right -> 0 and height as 40

Comment: did you add image in the attribute inspector of your imageView?

Comment: Thanks everyone. This issue fixed. Problem was image contentmode. When I set that to Scale to Aspect fill it worked.